# Minor sequence error in C++ program output

Tags: c++

I am trying to output "states" for any binary number that is inserted (for each 0 it outputs a random number between 1 & max), for example 10100 should output 2, random number between 1 & 2, 3, random number between 1 & 3, random number between 1 & 3. Thus looking like 21323 or 223212 or 21313, etc. But the output my program is giving me is 23456 - why?

```
int main()
{
    char binaryArray [0];
    int c1=1;
    int c0=0;
    int i=0;
    int n;

    cout << "Enter length of binary: "; //Length = total number of 1s & 0s
    cin >> n; 

    cout << "Enter binary number: ";
    cin >> binaryArray;

    cout << "States: ";

    for(i; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(binaryArray[i]=1)
        {
            c1++;
            cout << c1;
        }
        else if(binaryArray[i]=0)
        {
            c0++;
            cout << rand()%c1+1;  
        }
        /* if(c0 > c1)
        {
        cout << "Invalid Binary Representation.\n" << endl;
        exit(0); 
        } */
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `binaryArray[0]` is defined as a zero length array. You need to give it a length and make that an upper bound on the size of n. `const unsigned int MAX_LEN = 16; char binaryArray[MAX_LEN]; .... cout << "Enter length of binary max " << MAX_LEN << " : "`;

Comment: Why fiddle with character arrays when you can use a `std::string`?

Answer (score 3):

When you have an array of 0 (that is: zero) characters, you cannot save *anything* in it, not even a single bit. Make that array "large enough" (whatever that means for you) or better use a `std::string` instead.

Oh, and compile your code with all compiler warnings enabled. When you have understood and fixed all these warnings properly, you program should work much better. (Hint: assignment inside conditional)

Comment: Also, one should compare with `==`, not `=`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have assignment in the `if` statements. Use `==` instead of `=`.

Second, if you expect the number to be entered as binary and stored in `char` array, use `char` when comparing. So, your `if` statements should be:

```
//                vvvvvvv   
if( binaryArray[i] == '1' )
{
    c1++;
    cout << c1;
}
//                     vvvvvvv
else if( binaryArray[i] == '0' )
{
    c0++;
    cout << rand()%c1+1;  
}
```

Third, change the size of your array:

```
char binaryArray [0];
```

It **must** not be `0` here. Change it so something more common. Like `512`, for example, if you think that this will be big enough.

Comment: heyy thanks a lot I got it to work! I never knew about using the single quotation mark ' '

Comment: lol kk thanks, now the only problem I'm having is that the small code within the comment /*......*/ is not working, when c0 > c1 its suppose to output a message saying invalid because there are more 0s than 1s but it outputs numbers still, like if I enter 00000 it outputs 11111 instead of my invalid message

Comment: I need to see your code. Are you sure that you fixed all 3 things in my post?

Comment: yeah I changed to == '1' and == '0' and made the array [12] instead of [0]

Comment: There's something else then..paste your code in http://pastebin.com/ for example. Btw, I think the `if` should be outside the `for`, as what will happen if you enter "00011111111111111111111111" - will print an error, then twice `c1`, then error and number, error and number, etc. Or, if it should be before the `for`, count the zeroes and ones before the loop.

Comment: char binaryArray [12];
    int c1=1;
    int c0=0;
    int i=0;
    int n;
   cout << "Enter length of binary: "; 
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter binary number: ";
    cin >> binaryArray;
    cout << "States: ";
    for(i; i<n; i++)
    {
    if(binaryArray[i]== '1')
    {
        c1++;
        cout << c1;
     }
          
     else if(binaryArray[i]== '0')
     {
          c0++;
         cout << rand()%c1+1;  
     }
     if(c0 > c1)
     {
        cout << "Invalid Binary Representation.\n" << endl;
         exit(0); 
     }  
  }

Comment: It outputs `1111` because your `c1` is always 1 and everything `%1` is `0`, so you have `rand()%1 + 1` which gives you `0+1`. And I can't believe that the error message is not printed.

Comment: I put c1= 1 because there has to be a 1 since it is the root of the tree, if i input 10100 it already has the root 1 so it'll be 110100 thus being 1 2 (rand 1,2) 3 (rand 1,3) (rand 1,3) but the 1 (root) does not have to be shown, understand what I'm trying to say? sorry if you don't im new to this

Comment: Kinda..and what's the problem now? I explained the case with `00000`. What is the new issue?

Comment: when c0 is greater than c1 the invalid message doesnt print, and I'm still kind of stuck with what you said about the 00000

Comment: I just tested it, and it prints it..What number you enter, so that it does not print the error? Also, which part you don't understand of `00000` and its output `11111`? When `00000` is entered, ONLY the second if is executed, so `cout << rand()%c1+1;` is executed. BUT `c1` is always `1` in this case and any `any_number % 1` gives `0`.

Comment: number that I entered that does not print the error was 10100 and binary numbers that has more 0s than 1s has to print out the invalid message.

Comment: No, it doesn't. And it's because of the start value of `c1`. Which I didn't understand why it should start with `1` and what tree you're talking about..

Comment: Why don't you just debug step by step or just white down each step....it's a short number, just 5 digits! This can be done even without writing. Initially - c1=1; c0=0. First step - c1 = 2 (1+1); second step - c0 = 0 + 1; third step - c1++ -> c1 = 3; forth step - c0++ -> c0 = 2; fifth step -> again c0++ -> 3. Apparently `3==3`. You should learn to use debugger or just to write down things, when something does not work. Your logic is wrong. Fix it, it's not C++ question anymore.